# While loop and For loop together

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop, do-loops

Hi I want to run make for loop to run infinitely.

for eg.

```
while True:

    try:
     script()

except Exception as e:
        script()
        continue
```

as below because in For loop I have lists where i want to apply on scripts which run in sequencing and continuous

```
while True:
    try:
        for symbol in symbol:
            script()

    except Exception as e:
        for symbol in symbol:
            script()
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to run a program even when there is an exception and break at some condition, you do not want to run the loop infinitely I suppose. you can do

```
While true:
    try:
        for symbol in symbols:
            script(symbol) ' you should break however somewhere
    Exception as e:
        continue
```

Comment: There is nothing in this loop that will break the while loop, it will run forever